# What compare options does TFS use when merging?

Tags: tfs, merge, visual-studio-2015

We have recently run across some merging issues, in which a single file came up with a bunch of conflicts, and it was just severely messed up.  Our solution was to just take the source copy (we were Reverse Integrating) because there was no way to reconcile all the differences.  Then, upon check-in, that file was not checked in because the source version already matched the latest version in the target branch.

My initial thought was that since the person doing the merge had not done a get-latest first, it was comparing Workspace Version instead of Latest Version.  Is that a possibility?  And if so, is there a way to force TFS to always compare Latest Version when doing a merge?

Comment: If source branch matches target branch, why you need to perform a merge operation? And  when did you get the confilcts?

Comment: @Patrick The branches do not match, a single file within the branches matched, because we had previously merged the changes.  We were performing reverse integration to make sure all of our changes in the other branches were present in Main.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to force TFS always compare Latest Version when doing a merge. Since TFS merge the brach with the version what you choice.
But there is workaround to solve it.
For example:

You get the branch (changeset 98)to your local workspace to do same change.But the latest version in TFS server is changeset 100. After you finish your work, checking in the branch (get a changeset 101) , you could merge the branch(the latest version changeset 101) to your target branch.

Now the target branch including your changes in changeset 98 but not including the difference which between changest 100 and changest98. You need to merge branch again(choose changest 100) to the target branch. There maybe some conflicts, you can only manually solve it.

Finally,you have merged the latest branch including all changes to target brach.

Comment: It is not that there were not any changes to merge, just that this one single file that exists in both branches came up with a ton of conflicts during the merge operation.  Then, when we decided to take the source file to resolve the conflicts, that one file was not checked in, because they were actually exactly the same.

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding due to your first paragraph of the question. I have updated my reply as above. Hope it can be helpful

Answer (score 0):

To merge the latest version, you need to select **Latest Version** as Version Type.
[image]

Comment: Yes, but what is that compared against?  If you choose latest version here, does it take the latest version of the source branch, and compare that to the workspace version of the target branch, or does it also then use the latest version of the target branch?

Comment: It compares to the local workspace version of the target branch. And you will be prompted a warning said that there are some conflicts, you can resolve the conflicts with merge tool.

Comment: Thanks, that was our problem.  The person doing the merge had not first done a get-latest, and the conflicts were a result of that.